# Delay in SwiftUI view appearing

Tags: swiftui

I have a view that displays two calculated strings. At present, I calculate the strings with .onAppear. But the view does not render until the strings are calculated, leaving the user watching the previous view for 2 to 5 seconds till the calculation is done, and the progress bar never gets shown.
The code is:

```
struct CalculatingProgressView: View {
  var body: some View {
    ProgressView {
      Text("Calculating")
        .font(.title)
    }
  }
}

struct OffspringView: View {
  @State private var males: String = ""
  @State private var females: String = ""
  @State private var busy = true
  
  func determineOffspring() {

    let temp = theOffspring(of: sire, and: dam)
    males = temp.0
    females = temp.1
    
    busy = false
  }
  
  var body: some View {
    Section(header: Text("Male Offspring")) {
      Text(males)
        .font(.callout)
    }
    if busy {
      CalculatingProgressView()
    }
    Section(header: Text("Female Offspring")) {
      Text(females)
        .font(.callout)
    }
    .onAppear { determineOffspring() }
  }
}
```

How can I get the view to render with a progress bar so the user knows that the app is actually doing something?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). The `determineOffspring` function should be in your model. That model should be an `ObservableObject` and the offspring that get computed should be an `@Published` variable that is originally `nil`. you can then show the progress bar while `offspring` remains `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

your code seems to work for me. You could try this approach,
to show the `CalculatingProgressView` while it's calculating `determineOffspring`.

```
var body: some View {
        if busy {
            CalculatingProgressView()
                .onAppear { determineOffspring() }
        } else {
            Section(header: Text("Male Offspring")) {
                Text(males).font(.callout)
            }
            Section(header: Text("Female Offspring")) {
                Text(females).font(.callout)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note, your `theOffspring(...)` in `determineOffspring` should use a completion closure something like
the following, to "wait" until the calculations are finished:

```
func determineOffspring() {
    theOffspring(of: sire, and: dam) { result in
        males = result.0
        females = result.1
        busy = false
    }
}
```